# uncaught typeerror: cannot read property cookie of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, cookies

First of all I want to say that i've searched across the internet and could not find my answer anywhere.

I've tried to use jquery-coockie.js into my wordpress template, where i've created my own page for some kind of calculator.

When i'm trying to excecute my

```
if ($.cookie('cart')){
```

it gives me the error :

```
uncaught typeerror: cannot read property cookie of undefined
```

I've included my jquery-cookie.js correctly, so not-including is not giving me the problem.

[link to website](http://twirre.kweekvijvernoord.nl/calculator-test/)

Comment: Have you included jQuery itself?

Comment: You're using `.noConflict()`, which means that you have to use `tpj.cookie` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that jQuery is in noconflict mode.
Try this code:

```
jQuery.cookie('cart')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you've pasted indicates that JQuery is not defined. Did you include that earlier in the page?

In other locations on the page, you refer to JQuery by calling `jQuery(...)`, so it seems that you *do* have it, but it's stored as a different variable.

If you're controlling the line that fails (if it's not a part of that external Cookie script), use `jQuery.cookie(...)` instead.

If you don't control the script adding JQuery to the page, you could instead alias it to $ yourself -- `$ = jQuery;`